# Proper way to merge a nested map that might not exist

Tags: elixir

Given two possible inputs:
`a = %{ inner: %{hello: :world}}`

OR 
`a = %{}`

I want to merge `b = %{foo: :bar}` into the map to produce:

`%{inner: %{foo: :bar}}` in the first case or

`%{inner: %{hello: :world, foo: :bar}}` in the second.

I can solve it with

```
merged = Map.get(a, :inner, %{})
|> Map.merge(b)
put_in(a, [:inner], merged)
```

but is there a better inbuilt way? I would think that deep merging should be easier than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update_in/3` + `Access.key/2`:

```
iex(1)> a1 = %{ inner: %{hello: :world}}
%{inner: %{hello: :world}}
iex(2)> a2 = %{}
%{}
iex(3)> b = %{foo: :bar}
%{foo: :bar}
iex(4)> update_in(a1, [Access.key(:inner, %{})], &Map.merge(&1, b))
%{inner: %{foo: :bar, hello: :world}}
iex(5)> update_in(a2, [Access.key(:inner, %{})], &Map.merge(&1, b))
%{inner: %{foo: :bar}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Map.merge/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/3) function. The third argument is a function, which resolves the conflicts:

```
a = %{inner: %{hello: :world}}
b = %{foo: :bar}
Map.merge(a, %{inner: b}, fn _, m1, m2 -> Map.merge(m1, m2) end)
```

Thus, in this case, when a conflict occurs (both maps that are being merged have the same key), the provided function will be called. When `a` is `%{}`, no conflicts happen and `%{inner: %{foo: :bar}}` is returned.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. I've fixed the question

Comment: @AnilRedshift cool, so the second part of my response answered the question, I hope. But I updated the answer